# Oracle index that would optimize querying for rows whose ids are not inside a json array column

Tags: oracle

If I had a table with two columns

| Id | json_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1, 10, 11] |
| 2 | [] |

I could easily query the results using

```
SELECT M1.Id
  FROM MyTable M1
 WHERE Id NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 FROM MyTable M2, (JSON_TABLE(M2.JsonData, '$[*]'
                                 ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY NULL ON MISMATCH
                                 COLUMNS(
                                     Id NVARCHAR2(20) PATH '$'))) JT
                                 WHERE JT.Id = M1.Id)
```

Now how do I index this column so the query is not doint a full table scan?
MULTIVALUE indexes are used (I believe) for only JSON_EXISTS queries like this one

```
SELECT Id
  FROM MyTable WHERE NOT JSON_EXISTS(JsonData, '$?(@ == 1)')
```

but I can't use this function for non constant values such as `M1.Id`

Comment: Please note that most probably index will not be used for `not` predicate (at least I cannot recall such a case). Especially for this particular case because, at least,`null` values are not indexed and they will evaluate to `true` for this predicate. There's no place where Oracle extract required rowids except the table

Answer (score 1):

MULTIVALUE INDEX is available only in 21c and the array should be a field of a record, and the column must be JSON, it doesn't work with a CLOB with a CHECK constraint "IS JSON".

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9545758700346721260

```
create table t_test_ixjs (
    id number(10,0),
    json_data JSON
);
insert into t_test_ixjs(id,json_data) values(1,'{ "a" : [1, 10, 11] }') ;
insert into t_test_ixjs(id,json_data) values(2,'{ "a" : [] }') ;
create multivalue index ix_test_json_data on t_test_ixjs t ( t.json_data.a.number() );
with vals(d) as (
    select 1 from dual
)
SELECT *
  FROM vals v, 
  t_test_ixjs WHERE JSON_EXISTS(json_data, '$.a?(@ == $d)' PASSING v.d AS "d")
;

Plan hash value: 1205791918
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                   |     1 | 20513 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T_TEST_IXJS       |     1 | 20513 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   HASH UNIQUE                       |                   |     1 | 20513 |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN (MULTI VALUE)   | IX_TEST_JSON_DATA |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: And how do I use the `t_test_ixjs.id` instead of constant "1" ?

Comment: Indeed... ORA-40576  "Invalid use of bind variable in SQL/JSON path."
*Cause:    An attempt was made to bind a non-runtime constant to a bind variable in SQL/JSON path.
This one will be more annoying to avoid. Would be very painful to have to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE...

Comment: Or add a calculated column with an index on it:
idinjson NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (regexp_instr(json_data, '[^\d]' || id || '[^\d]'))

Comment: I'll try with the generated column

Comment: My bad, my use case has to check every json_data from every row, so no good.

Comment: Not sure to understand this latest one: you have to check every id in every json_data?
How would be presented the result?

Comment: My query has to returns ids that are not present in any row (json_data column)

Comment: select id from t_test_ixjs
minus
select t1.id 
from 
 (select id from t_test_ixjs) t1, 
 t_test_ixjs t2
where 
 (regexp_instr(t2.json_data, '[^[:digit:]]' || t1.id || '[^[:digit:]]') > 0)
;

Comment: Yes, but I can't make a virtual column like you said earlier?

Comment: It's no more needed because it checks only the id within the json_data of the same row, unless you need to answer that question in other context.

Comment: So, no index? ..

Comment: A multivalue index will not be used but you can try a SEARCH index, little chance it will be used. If you want more performance, you will have to normalize the model and expand the JSON array into an intersection table.